# Add a string to string values of an inner list

Tags: python, html, list

Ok, so I have this list,

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I']]
```

I want to add html tags to the values in the inner lists.

How would I go about doing this?

i.e.

```
[['<b>A</b>', '<b>B</b>', '<b>C</b>'], ['<b>D</b>', '<b>E</b>', '<b>F</b>'], ['<b>G</b>', '<b>H</b>', '<b>I</b>']]
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895449/merging-a-list-of-lists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[['<b>%s</b>' % x for x in data] for data in my_list]
```

Comment: You were faster. I was ready to paste in a very similar answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
def AddHtml(s): return '<b>' + s + '</b>'

def AddHtmlArray(a) : return map(AddHtml, a)

...

map(AddHtmlArray, yourList)
```

Comment: I like the self-documenting functional pieces.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I']]

>>> out = [['<b>'+s+'</b>' for s in subl] for subl in l]

>>> out
[['<b>A</b>', '<b>B</b>', '<b>C</b>'], ['<b>D</b>', '<b>E</b>', '<b>F</b>'], ['<b>G</b>', '<b>H</b>', '<b>I</b>']]
```