# adding each member of an array again, right after itself

Tags: python, data-structures, recursive-datastructures

if I have this Python array:

```
mac_tags = [ "global_rtgn", "global_mogn" ]
```

And I want this Python array:

```
mac_tags = [ "global_rtgn", "global_rtgn", "global_mogn","global_mogn" ]
```

How might I create it programmatically?

Comment: _Why_ do you want that? Just modify whatever's using the list to duplicate entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new_mac_tags = []
for tag in mac_tags:
    new_mac_tags += [tag, tag]
```

or

```
from itertools import chain, izip
new_mac_tags = list(chain.from_iterable(izip(mac_tags, mac_tags)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [a for a in mac_tags for x in range(2)]
['global_rtgn', 'global_rtgn', 'global_mogn', 'global_mogn']
```

Comment: Not going to argue here, it's just another way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

```
[i for i in sorted(mac_tags+mac_tags)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Please note that this is more of a functional way of doing this and may not be pure idiomatic python code.

```
data = [[s, s] for s in [ "global_rtgn", "global_mogn" ]]

data = sum (data, [])

print data
```

Comment: (a) This seems like an abuse of `sum` (b) by using sum, you lose the ability to use zip/izip instead of writing your own.

Comment: @Marcin: The worst problem with this approach is that it is O(n^2).

Comment: @SvenMarnach: How so? Surely one traversal for the zipping, plus one traversal for the sum. Or do you mean that memory allocation will be O(n^2)? Is CPython unable to optimise this?

Comment: @Marcin: The `+` operator on lists creates a new list. Using `sum()` here creates a new list in every iteration, copying everything that has been accumulated so far. It would be possible to optimise this, but it isn't trivial to do, and CPython doesn't.  This use of `sum()` is considered wrong, so no efforts will be made to optimise it.  Using a list comprehension with two `for` clauses or `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` are considered the right ways. In fact, it is more likely that future Python version reject this use of `sum()` (as they already to for strings) than that it gets optimised.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I understand the python-level semantics of `+`, but there is still no reason why it *has* to copy every time, rather than optimising the concatenation.

Comment: @Marcin: It has to copy in the first step, since it is not allowed to modify the object passed in as the `start` parameter.  And the implementation basically invokes the `__add__()` method of whatever objects it gets.  Optimising this for lists would need some special-casing in the implementation of `sum()`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach No, it wouldn't require any special casing in `sum`. All it would require is for `__add__` to be optimised where the left operand has no references to it outside of the calling context and the next thing that is going to happen to it is that it is going to be the left operand of another `__add__` call. In that case, an optimising compiler could simply extend the array backing the left operand, and copy the contents of the right operand into the new space. It's not an insanely complex optimisation.

Comment: @Marcin: No, it wouldn't be as easy as this because it would change the C interface in an incompatible way.  A reference count of 1 means there are no further Python references, but a calling C function could still very well hold an external reference -- [I discussed exactly this before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7895490/279627).  This means the optimisation would have to be done in `sum()`, and it would need to special-case lists.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yes, obviously I am talking about a change to the way the python interpreter itself works. You only need a specific optimisation in `sum` if you assume *no other changes whatsoever to any code*.