# Merging lists of lists

Tags: python, list, merge

I have two lists of lists that have equivalent numbers of items. The two lists look like this:

`L1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]`

`L2 =[[a, b], [c, d], [e, f, g]]`

I am looking to create one list that looks like this:

`Lmerge = [[[a, 1], [b,2]], [[c,3], [d,4]], [[e,5], [f,6], [g,7]]]`

I was attempting to use `map()` :

`map(list.__add__, L1, L2)` but the output produces a flat list.

What is the best way to combine two lists of lists? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probable duplication with ["Merging a list of lists"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895449/merging-a-list-of-lists) from October 2011?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `zip` the lists and then `zip` the resulting tuples again...

```
>>> L1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
>>> L2 =[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]
>>> [list(zip(a,b)) for a,b in zip(L2, L1)]
[[('a', 1), ('b', 2)], [('c', 3), ('d', 4)], [('e', 5), ('f', 6), ('g', 7)]]
```

If you need lists all the way down, combine with `map:

```
>>> [list(map(list, zip(a,b))) for a,b in zip(L2, L1)]
[[['a', 1], ['b', 2]], [['c', 3], ['d', 4]], [['e', 5], ['f', 6], ['g', 7]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right track with the `map`.

Here's a shorter alternative to the first version by tobias_k, `zip` together corresponding elements from both lists:

```
>>> zipped = map(zip, L2, L1)
>>> list(map(list, zipped)) # evaluate to a list of lists
[[('a', 1), ('b', 2)], [('c', 3), ('d', 4)], [('e', 5), ('f', 6), ('g', 7)]]
```

As noted in the comments, in Python 2, the brief `map(zip, L2, L1)` is enough.

`map(zip, L2, L1)` will work for you in Python 3 too, given that you iterate over it just once and that you don't need sequence access by index. And if you need to iterate many times, you may be interested in [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee).

A shorter alternative to the second version:

```
>>> [list(map(list, x)) for x in map(zip, L2, L1)]
[[['a', 1], ['b', 2]], [['c', 3], ['d', 4]], [['e', 5], ['f', 6], ['g', 7]]]
```

Lastly, there's also this:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> map(partial(map, list), map(zip, L2, L1))
[[['a', 1], ['b', 2]], [['c', 3], ['d', 4]], [['e', 5], ['f', 6], ['g', 7]]]
```

Comment: Nice. In fact, in Python 2, the first one is equivalent to just `map(zip, L2, L1)` -- but you'd probably need at least as many characters to explain what this does. ;-)

Comment: @tobias_k: Thanks for pointing this out. I assumed we were talking Python 3 and that OP really needs a list. But for other people, the shortest version may be suitable even if they ditched Python 2. Arguably, it may actually be the most readable, at least for people familiar with `map` and `zip`.