# How can i merge some lists element by element

Tags: python-3.x, list, merge

I have 3 lists and want to merge them as a list by using map not just zip.

```
a=[1,1,1,1]
b=[2,2,2,2]
c=[3,3,3,3]
```

I want to obtain list bellow

```
f=[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

i am using python3 would you please educate me how can i do?

Comment: So, what have you tried? Also, is it safe to assume that the 3 lists have the same length?

Comment: by using zip(a,b,c) i can get final list. but its not as a list, and also according to this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503922/merging-lists-of-lists/53370703#53370703 , i have tried to do it but i got some errors about zip and map. it looks in python3 they do not work as pervius version. i am a beginner in python

Comment: yes all the lists have same lenght

Comment: `list(map(list,zip(a,b,c)))`

Comment: `[list(i) for i in zip(a,b,c)]`

Comment: thank you :) , yes i also made a zip then transform to list style but yours is a shorter way, great !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a simple loop. Loop through the index and create a list of the elements for each list at that particular index. Then append that list to the `f`.

```
f = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    f.append([a[i], b[i], c[i]])
print(f)
```

Comment: thank you, right, its much easier than map and zip functions :)